# How to compute the parameters of circumscribed hypershpere?

Tags: geometry

Assume I have an $n$-dimensional simplex on the points $x_0, ..., x_n$, where each $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to obtain the parameters (center and radius) of it's circumscribed $n$-dimensional hypershpere. How can I do that?

Comment: Everything is in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/03ee/b4852c4e7e8a33ecc6b3184ec515f844d5cd.pdf. See as well https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304475/centroid-and-center-circumscribed-spheres-in-simplex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x_i$ write $x_i=(x_{i1},\ldots,x_{in})$. Let $c=(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ be the center and $R$ the radius of the circumscribed hypersphere. Note that $|x_i-c|=R$ for all $0\leqslant i\leqslant n$, so $|x_i-c|=|x_0-c|$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$. To find $c$ we solve this system, or we solve the equivalent system $|x_i-c|^2=|x_0-c|^2$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$. Note that $|x_i-c|^2=|x_0-c|^2$ is written like this:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(x_{ik}-c_k)^2=\sum_{k=1}^n(x_{0k}-c_k)^2,$$
which is by rearranging equivalent to:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n2(x_{0k}-x_{ik})c_k=\sum_{k=1}^nx_{0k}^2-x_{ik}^2.$$
Note that the right hand side is just $|x_0|-|x_i|$. So $c$ is the solution of the linear system:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2(x_{01}-x_{11}) & 2(x_{02}-x_{12}) & \cdots & 2(x_{0n}-x_{1n})\\
2(x_{01}-x_{21}) & 2(x_{02}-x_{22}) & \cdots & 2(x_{0n}-x_{2n})\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
2(x_{01}-x_{n1}) & 2(x_{02}-x_{n2}) & \cdots & 2(x_{0n}-x_{nn})
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_0\\c_1\\\vdots\\c_n
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
|x_0|-|x_1|\\|x_0|-|x_2|\\\vdots\\|x_0|-|x_n|
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Since we started from a simplex, i.e. $x_i$'s are affinely independend, then $(x_0-x_i)$'s are linearly independent, so the previous system has a unique solution. So, this is how we find $c$, and then we calculate $R=|x_0-c|$.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the vertices are on the edge of the sphere, or am I misreading it?

Comment: @DanielV Yes, we are looking for the circumscribed sphere.